# How to get name of named constructor parameter in Dart?

Tags: dart

Example:

```
Class User {
    String name;
    String age;
    String hobby;

    User({this.name, this.age, this.hobby});
}
```

If I use `user.name`, I will get the name value, but how do I get the name of 'name' parameter? I saw this is possible in some other languages like C# and Javascript, but can't find it for Dart.

Comment: I'm confused.  Maybe terminology.  "named constructor" means a constructor with a name, like `User.boring({required this.name, required this.age, this.hobby = 'sleeping'});`.

Comment: I know what it means, I am asking how to get the name of the named constructor. So in your example I am asking how to get the 'hobby' as it is the named constructor. So I dont need the hobby value which is 'sleeping', I need the 'hobby' which is the name of argument.

Comment: No, the name of the constructor is User.boring, so I'm confused by the clarification. :)

Comment: Ahh. The metainformation of "name". Not available.